# Better way to Find which element has a specific class from an array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Suppose I have a List like the following

```
  <ul>
     <li id="slide-a" class="slide-li active-slide"><a href="#" >A</a></li>
     <li id="slide-b" class="slide-li"><a href="#" >B</a></li>
     <li id="slide-c" class="slide-li"><a href="#" >C</a></li                        
  </ul>
```

Now , using Jquery I wanna Find out which Element has the class `'active-class'`. One way would to have a nested if statement something like this:

```
if($("#slide-a").hasClass('active-slide'))
{
  active = 'slide-a';
}
else
{
  if($("#slide-b").hasClass('active-slide'))
  {
    active = 'slide-b';
  }
  else
  {
    if($("#slide-c").hasClass('active-slide'))
    {
      active = 'slide-c';
    }
  }
}
```

My question is if there exists any way to optimize the code above. Is there a generic way to achieve this such that even if I add 10 more li's in the ul the code just works fine without any modification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe just

```
var active = $(".active-slide").attr("id");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82nC3/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li[id^=slide]').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active-slide'))
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/6EY2S/)**

If you have more than one li with class`active-slide` use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idVal = [];
    $('li[id^=slide]').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active-slide'))
            idVal.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    console.log(idVal);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/6EY2S/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could a use jQuery [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) on the ul to iterate through.

fiddle coming in a second.

Comment: check out what unknown did.